# How to add some footer note (msg) in Standalone Jetty for a static page : http://localhost:8080/jcg/

Tags: java, xml, jetty

I configured Resource Handler for Standalone Jetty. The configuration just in XML format. The steps followed by me:
1.Open jetty.xml file which is under JETTY_HOME/etc.
2.Add the Resource Handler XML configuration to the handler element(which is given below)
3.Save the file and run Jetty.

i tried to add some tag but i am getting below error

HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /jcg. 
Reason:Not Found
Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.9.v20160517

The handler element in jetty.xml seems as follows:

```
<Set name="handler">

<New id="Handlers"class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">

<Set name="handlers">

<Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">

<Item>

<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">

<Set name="contextPath">/jcg</Set>

<Set name="handler">

<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">

<Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>

<Set name="resourceBase">/Users/ibrahim/jcgexamples/jcgresources</Set>

</New>

</Set>

</New>

</Item>

<Item>

<New id="Contexts"class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>

</Item>

<Item>

<New id="DefaultHandler"class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>

</Item>
```

```
</New>

</Set>
```

note: Here, we have set the context root as /jcg; enabled directory listing and set the resource base with an absolute path.

I want display some msg for user on web page, how to do that? which tag to use and where to use?